# ZooVisitor Registration issue (password confirmation)

Tags: zoo-visitor, password, register, zoo

I'm having issues with the password confirmation in Zoo Visitor Registration.
If I enter two separate passwords for the password and password_confirm fields then the user is still registered.

Any thoughts why this might be happening or how to fix?

Code sample at https://gist.github.com/cole007/5d68d989545cb5cfc45a

Cheers,

Cole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you disable "require password confirmation" in the settings? http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/start/overview.html#flexible-member-data-settings

Comment: Great thanks - what a n00b!

Answer (score 0):

on your code sample you're using a conditional for the password and password_confirm value attribute.

```
{if password}value="{password}"{/if}
{if password_confirm} value="{password_confirm}"{/if}
```

The value attribute should be empty.